# email as username to login joomla 3.4

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I can't set an email to perform a login in my site. I create a plugin authentication to override the existing one where I change the SQL query to select id and password:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('id, password')
    ->from('#__users')
    ->where('**email**=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));
```

I also tried to modify `login.xml` as below:

```
 <field name="username"
        type="email"
        class="validate-email"
        filter="email"
        label="COM_USERS_LOGIN_EMAIL_LABEL"
        size="25"
        required="true"
        validate="email"
        />
```

When I try to login I get:

```
You can't access to the private section of the site
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you check what is contained in `$credentials['username']` and `$credentials`?

Comment: I did an echo of credentials array and it contains exactly the mail and the password. Maybe there is a problem in server side validation?

Comment: I partialy solved....i overrided the controller user.php getting the username from the mail passed in the form with a query mysql. But Now after login i'm ever redirect to home...before redirection works fine to profile page...How works return url???

Comment: edit: I'm redirected to home with ERROR: You are not authorized to view this resource. but i can go to the profile page trough the menu item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, and i want to share my solution:
you don't need to modify joomla.php of authentication plugin.

You have to modify controller `user.php` in `/components/com_users/controllers` as below:

```
$data['email']  = $input->$method->get('email', '', 'EMAIL');
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('username')
    ->from('#__users')
    ->where('email=' . $db->quote($data['email']));
$db->setQuery($query);
$utente = $db->loadResult();
$data['username'] = $utente;
```

In this way you select the correct username using the email passed in the form.

Now you can modify the form of login (`/components/com_users/models/form/login.xml` changing all occurences of "username" with "email" (see below):

```
    <field
            name="email"
            type="email"
            class="validate-email"
            filter="email"
            label="E-mail"
            size="25"
            required="true"
            validate="email"
    />
```

then u have to modify jmessage in case of login failed in your language files.

That's all!

(for post-login redirection, adding the Itemid in the url it backs to work....)

In these way I edited core files and i don't like.
is there anyway to make a good override of com_users?

Answer (score -1):

it wouldn't have been simpler:

**Register**

- hide the username field (CSS)
- saving (during creation and editing), fill in the username field with the value of that email. (I'm not a developer and cannot help here) Maybe, Do you have an idea / suggestion ?

**Login**

- with a simple language override change the "Username" label with "Email" (the same in emails and alerts)